# webcam permission request doesnt work with local files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

When experimenting some things with WebRTC. I looked at some examples and downloaded one from [github](https://github.com/webRTC/webrtc.io-demo). This wasn't working at all. At the right side of the url, there was an icon that indicated that my webcam was blocked. I clicked on it and said that it could use my webcam. Then chrome said to reload the page so i did that. And everything was the same as in the beginning. But when I loaded the same site through jsfiddle, it asked me with a pop-up for webcam access (the same way as every other application does) and that worked without a flaw. I tested some other browsers and it was all the same. Does anyone have a suggestion how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use the web cam API, the file must be run from a server. When tyou run it from JSFiddle, it runs on a server, and thus works. It wont work if you run it as a `file:///` in your browser, you must run a local web server on your computer and open the web app from there as `http://`

**Running a server**

Well running a webserver could be very complex, and requires knoweldege in using softwares like apache or ISS. Luckily enough, for develpers just seeking a simple, straight forward webserver for client side development, there are a couple of easy solutions:

- Windows: use a software called WAMP - it automaticaly runs apache on your machiene and creates a folder on your computer in which you can put all the website content. http://www.wampserver.com/en/
- Mac: simillar to WAMP, mac has a piece of software called XAMP that does pretty much the same thing. http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Both are pretty simple, but I think will be enough for simple front end development.

Comment: then, how should i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome blocked my webcam on a site where I denied access multiple times (because I was testing).

You might need to visit chrome://settings/contentExceptions#media-stream and clear your settings.